# Get values from othersheet to other based on conditions in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I have sheet with data, i want to get data in other sheet but with conditions.For ex:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Cell A   | Cell B |  Cell C    | Cell D|Cell E |        
|------------------------------------------------|
| Sku      |Order_ID|Customer_ID | Price |Status | 
|------------------------------------------------|
| TW22     |   123  |    1       |221    |   D   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| TS44     |  124   |     2      |221    |   D   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| Ts11-ab  |   33   |     3      |211    |   D   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| Ts11     |   231  |     4      |231    |   D   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| Ts11-ab  |   33   |     3      |211    |   R   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| Ts11     |   231  |     4      |231    |   R   |
|------------------------------------------------|
```

I have data in sheet as above in ex:, Now i want values like bellow in my other sheet ex:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Cell A   | Cell B |  Cell C    | Cell D|Cell E |        
|------------------------------------------------|
| Sku      |Order_ID|Customer_ID | Price |Status | 
|------------------------------------------------|
| TW22     |   123  |    1       |221    |   D   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| TS44     |  124   |     2      |221    |   D   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| Ts11-ab  |   33   |     3      |211    |   R   |
|------------------------------------------------|
| Ts11     |   231  |     4      |231    |   R   |
|------------------------------------------------|
```

I have tried vlookup and other formulas find from net but not helpful as i need.

update : If an order ID has two records in Sheet 1 with status “D” and “R”, it should show entry with just status “R” in the Sheet 2.And if there is only one record with status “D”, then it should show that record in the sheet 2. thanks

Comment: What decides which to return?

Comment: Share what formulas you have tried. You may be close and don't know it.

Comment: hi @ScottCraner order id

Comment: @CharlieRB =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!E:E,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$14<>"",ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$14)),ROWS(Sheet2!$A$2:$A2))),"") try this one

Comment: You have two order_id of 33 why one and not the other?

Comment: @ScottCraner main i want the status of the order so in this case user order product its show D when your return the product its show R . so in this case  Customer_id 3 order product and return product .in this sheet Customer_id remain same and order_id also remain same . just status of order change . in my sheet the data of order's status store in same column . so i want to refine this data with order status . thanks hope you understand

Comment: Please use the [edit] feature to update your post with these details. It makes it difficult for people who read the question to have to sort thru comments to get the additional details.

Comment: @CharlieRB thanks for suggest this . i edit the question and now hope i will get some solution as well .

Comment: @ScottCraner please read my question now may be you understand this time .. thanks

Comment: I am sorry. I am having difficulty understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: @CharlieRB as above my example show that if order id have 2 status in column "E" like "D" and "R"  i want to show "R" in front of order id in sheet 2 .  "D" represent  order delivered and "R" represent order return . so if order return in sheet two i want to show "R"  for  example  as i given above in my question with order id 33 customer return my product . so in main sheet it have two values for same order one order deliver to customer and next row show order return by customer . so i have lot of data want to refine with just one value in sheet 2 if order not return show d if return show r

Comment: @biz: it's very difficult to follow your requirements through all the comments. Please edit your question and include all the information from the comments. Also please try to reduce the text, people here are unlikely to read so long text.

Comment: @MátéJuhász please see now my question hope you understand now

Comment: So do all SKU/Order ID cases have one and only one D status record, and some also have one and only one R status record, and the goal is to eliminate the D status record if there's a replacement R status record?

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes, exactly

Comment: @biz, I'll need more coffee before thinking about a solution.  However, it's hard to imagine that this general type of problem hasn't been asked here before; at least something close.  The "related questions" listed on the side are just ones with similar keywords, and the built-in search box at the top isn't always that powerful a tool for finding similar questions.  Google is often actually better at finding things in Super User.  It might give you a jump start to look for any search terms you can think of.

Comment: @fixer1234 thanks for your time . hope fixed it by my self by learning things from google .